# Unable to navigate to form action in IE and Edge when using input type image

Tags: html, forms, input, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

When using an image input with a formaction attribute inside of a form in IE and Edge, clicking on the input image does not navigate to the specified formaction external URL. If you are currently viewing this question in Chrome and run the code snippet below, it will correctly open the Apache website. However, if you re-open this page in Edge, you'll find that clicking on the button does not work. However, if you change the input type to submit, everything works fine. Does anyone know why this is happening or if it's documented anywhere?

```html
<form method='POST' id='loginForm'>
  <input type='image' formaction='https://apache.org' src='http://apache.org/images/SupportApache-small.png' height='20%'  />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with your code and I am able to produce the issue. Looks like IE and MS Edge has some issue with the **formaction** in Input type Image.

Workaround is to remove the **formaction** from an Image and put it in the form like below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method='POST' id='loginForm' action="https://apache.org">
  <input type='image'  src='http://apache.org/images/SupportApache-small.png' height='20%'  />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE:

[image]

Similar output you will get in MS Edge and other browsers.

Comment: My actual scenario had multiple submit buttons so that's why I was using the formaction attribute for each input rather than the action attribute on the form. I should have been more clear in my question. Also, I am guessing there are a number of ways to solve this with javascript, but I would prefer to have a non-javascript solution if possible.

Comment: I try to find the solution using the HTML but looks like no any solution or work around available for this issue. So it is better that you use JS to work around this issue. If you are ok to use JS than let me know. I will try to find work around using JS for this issue. I had already submitted the feedback for MS Edge regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP didn't specifically ask for a solution, only for an explanation/documentation, I'm posting a workaround (using jquery), in case anyone comes here looking for one:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('form').submit(function () {
    var btn = $(this).find("input[type=image]:focus");
    if (btn.length == 1) {
        this.action = btn[0].formAction;
    }
  });
}
```